# How to use mlr package wrapped model as it is?

Tags: r, mlr

Model

```
rf.lrn.base = makeLearner("classif.randomForest", predict.type = "prob",fix.factors.prediction=TRUE)
rf.lrn <- makeFilterWrapper(rf.lrn.base,fw.method = "chi.squared", fw.perc = 0.5)
rf.lrn
```

Tuning

```
tune_rdesc.rf <- makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 3L, stratify = TRUE)
rf_ps <- makeParamSet(makeDiscreteParam("fw.perc", values = seq(0, 1, 0.1)),
                         makeIntegerParam("ntree", lower = 10, upper = 50), 
                         makeIntegerParam("mtry", lower = 10, upper = 40)
                         )
Tuned_rf <- tuneParams(rf.lrn, task = classif.task,resampling = tune_rdesc.rf,par.set = rf_ps,control = makeTuneControlGrid())
```

Wrapper

```
fused_rf <- makeFilterWrapper(rf.lrn.base,fw.method = "chi.squared",fw.perc = Tuned_rf$x$fw.perc)
```

Fit

```
rf_mod <- mlr::train(fused_rf, classif.task)
rf_mod
```

Prediction, Below gives the table of truth, prob.0, prob.1, response, From here I can access pred_rf$data$prob.0 and pred_rf$data$prob.1 seperately

```
pred_rf <- predict(rf_mod, newdata = Test_WOE_clean)
pred_rf$data
```

Below gives only response

```
randomForest <- getLearnerModel(rf_mod, more.unwrap = TRUE)
pred_rf2 <- predict(randomForest, newdata = Test_WOE_clean)
pred_rf2
```

Now I want to transform the model to PMML file using pmml package (Predictive Model Markup Language)

```
library(pmml)
rf_pmml <- pmml(model=randomForest)
```

Above produces an Error as

```
Error in UseMethod("pmml") : 
  no applicable method for 'pmml' applied to an object of class "c('FilterModel', 'BaseWrapperModel', 'WrappedModel')"
```

But the below doesn't

```
randomForest <- getLearnerModel(rf_mod, more.unwrap = TRUE)
rf_pmml <- pmml(model=randomForest)
```

Same with for converting to PFA (portable format for analytics) using library(aurelius)

Another Issue is for uploading to AzureML

```
rf.inputdata <- as.data.frame(subset(Train_WOE_clean,select=-c(Target)))

rf.PredictT <- function(inputdata){
  predict(rf_mod,newdata=inputdata)
}

library(AzureML)
library(devtools)

#workspace 
rf.ws <- workspace(
  id = "**************",
  auth = "**************",
  api_endpoint = "https://studioapi.azureml.net"
)


rf.TWebService <- publishWebService(rf.ws,
                                    fun=rf.PredictT,
                                    name="rf_mod",
                                    inputSchema = rf.inputdata)
```

So I will get the model as web service in AzureML, I can do prediction there, but it is producing Error

```
no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "c('FilterModel', 'BaseWrapperModel', 'WrappedModel')
```

May I know How to solve the 4 Issues,

1. pmml conversion
2. pfa conversion
3. Error in AzureML
4. mlr package is not listed as supported packages in AzureML, so please may I know How to install mlr package in AzureML workspace.
5. For Deployment, I am looking on "Deploy R Model in production", as you said Use R code to deploy, may I know some links to study that.

Comment: You need to be more specific -- what exactly do you want to do with the model, or its predictions? How is your production environment different from development? What exactly are the issues that you're seeing in the production environment?

Comment: Thanks for reply, if I want to convert the model to pmml
I use 
pmml(model=rf_mod_wrapped) 

I am getting Error as:

Error in UseMethod("pmml") :
no applicable method for 'pmml' applied to an object of class "c('FilterModel', 'BaseWrapperModel', 'WrappedModel')"

Comment: Below works, but I am looking for the previous one to work
u_randomForest <- getLearnerModel(rf_mod_wrapped, more.unwrap = TRUE)
pmml(model=u_randomForest)

Comment: Same to Convert to PFA file
rf_pfa <- pfa(rf_mod_wrapped, pred_type='prob')
Error in UseMethod("pfa") :
no applicable method for 'pfa' applied to an object of class "c('FilterModel', 'BaseWrapperModel', 'WrappedModel')"
Below Works
u_randomForest <- getLearnerModel(rf_mod_wrapped, more.unwrap = TRUE)
rf_pfa <- pfa(u_randomFores, pred_type='prob')

Comment: Also when is publish that in AzureML, using publishWebService function, I am getting same error

Comment: As it works when you unwrap the model, I don't see the problem. Why not just unwrap the model?

Comment: When we unwrap we get prediction as 0/1, but without we get probabilities as percentage when we access truth, response, prob.0, prob1

Comment: That sounds like a bug -- can you give a complete example that demonstrates the problem please?

Comment: Sure,I will load the codes, Also when I deploy the mlr model in AzureML as a web service, I am getting same error, just would like to know the possible ways to deploy mlr models

Comment: Again, "deploy mlr models" isn't really specific enough. You can just use it in R code to "deploy" it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191218/discussion-between-prem-and-lars-kotthoff).

Comment: Hi Lars, Hope I get some feedback please, Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `predict(randomForest, newdata = Test_WOE_clean, type = "prob")`?

Comment: No, will try that, but the prediction object has only a vector, not a data frame of truth, response,probs,

Comment: Yes, predict(randomForest, newdata = Test_WOE_clean, type = "prob") Works.
pred_rf2 <- predict(QBE_randomForest, newdata = Test_WOE_clean, type = "prob")
pred_rf2
pred_rf3 <- predict(QBE_randomForest, newdata = Test_WOE_clean, type = "response")
pred_rf3

pred_rf2 gives probability of 0,1
pred_rf3 gives responses

That surely helps, Thank you very much

Comment: May I please know regarding the AzureML upload, the unwrap model in the predict function with type="response" or "prob" gives the following Error

no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "c('randomForest.formula', 'randomForest')" 

I gave require(mlr) not working, library(mlr) says no package, may I know how to load mlr via these function in AzureML please, Thanks


As I said AzureML don't have mlr in the supported list.

Comment: Sorry, don't know anything about AzureML.